# Alert on Custom metric do not fire even when the threshold is crossed

Tags: azure-application-insights, alerts, azureportal

We have an application which uses Application Insights to Track the telemetry.

I have some custom metrics (say x) which i pass from the Application. The Metrics explores shows the details .

We wanted to have an alert bases on the Value of the Custom metric x.I create an Alert  on the Portal by going to Alerts tab and Add metric alert.

The custom metric is shown in the dropdown of the Metric. Rest of the parameters are set.

But no alert is fired and no email notification is sent even when the condition is met.

Please help me to figure out the issue.

I tried setting various other combinations for threshold and Period, but nothing seem to have worked.

I made sure that while creating the alert the alert condition is not true.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loQko.png)